# Truffle Console: How to print the value of a variable using get function

Tags: truffle, truffle-console

I want to printthe value of iVar:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
   contract PRetVal {
      uint8  iVar =0;
      function testFunc() public returns (uint8) {
         iVar = iVar + 10;
         return iVar;
      }
   }
```

I am trying the following :

```
truffle(development)> PR = await PRetVal.at(0x596D30c26211B4Dab998F63D6Bf5eba55B0B1d2D) 
undefined
truffle(development)> await PR.getIVar 
undefined truffle(development)>
```

But I am not getting any value. Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a couple of changes to see the value of `iVar`:

1. Make it **public** in order to generate a getter function:

   `uint8 public iVar = 0;`

2. Call the variable with parenthesis (because it is now public and has a getter):

   `truffle(development)> await PR.getIVar()`

Alternatively, you could also add a function in the contract to retrieve the value, such as:

```
function getiVar() external view returns(uint8){
    return iVar;
}
```

Comment: I am getting > PR.getiVar()
<BN: a>
what is the meaning of BN?

Comment: This is 'Big Number' type, so you can do a conversion such as :    PR.iVar().then(result => console.log(result.toNumber()))